# Some functions if the Telegram Bot WebApp is not working

Tags: api, web-applications, bots, telegram, qr-code

thanks for your attention.

This is a simple webpage for a web-app bot.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
  <head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /> 
    <title>Bot Web App</title> 
    <script src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js"></script> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
 <button onclick="Telegram.WebApp.HapticFeedback.impactOccurred('heavy');">Feedback</button> 
 <button onclick="Telegram.WebApp.expand();">Expand WebView</button> 
 <button onclick="Telegram.WebApp.close();">Close  WebView</button> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Expand and close button working fine. The issue is with haptic feedback.

It is not working, not even the showScanQrPopup() or some other functions.

Can anyone tell me what is the issue? Or how to do them if my method is wrong?

My final target is to create a telegram bot that will scan a qr code and send the code data to the server to process. And the server (bot) will send a confirmation message. The qr code must be scanned like [@easyqrscanbot](https://t.me/easyqrscanbot)